# Convert URLs to an HTML file with filename as link text

Tags: html, url, text, hyperlink

I have a bunch of Direct Links (URLs) and I need to put them in an HTML file so I can access them by clicking on. I used an online tool to convert them to HTML type, but when I opened the HTML, the URLs were used as the link text. how can I use the file name as showing Link text?
here is what I put in the HTML file. I need to use "filename.rar" as the link text.

```
<a href="uploaded.net/s/qwrlkqjwrkljqwr/filename.rar?dl=0">uploaded.net/s/oiqetoetjwasfajfu/filename.rar?dl=0</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Part in between the `<a></a>` Tags is what a user sees as Text. So changing your Code to

```html
<a href="uploaded.net/s/qwrlkqjwrkljqwr/filename.rar?dl=0">filename.rar</a>
```

would show up as expected.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I knew that but the problem is I have about 10000 URLs to add. and it's not possible to do this for all of them manually. is there any automated tool for that?

Comment: if the path is always the same you could use a Texteditor like `Notepad++` and use "search and replace" like this ">uploaded.net/s/oiqetoetjwasfajfu/" -> ">". (Adding the ">" to the search prevents deleting the link in the `<a>` Tag)

Comment: If the Path is changing you could use a Regular Expression to match the pattern, but I would advise you to open another question for that, as regular Expressions can be a bit tricky sometimes.

Comment: thanks. I used Regular Expression to solve my issue and it's done now. the code I use is here: >dl[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/